# How to import libraries in Coq?

Tags: coq

I want to use `&&` as infix form of `andb` in Coq. Official documentation tells me `&&` is defined in `Coq.Init.Datatypes` module.
I tried this:
`Import Coq.Init.Datatypes.`

Still Coq gives error:

```
Unknown interpretation for notation "_ && _".
```

What is the correct way to include Std library in Coq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Locate` command to get some information on this:

```
Locate "&&".
```

Here is its output:

> ```
> Notation            Scope
> "x && y" := andb x y : bool_scope
> ```

The [manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual014.html#scopes) says that

> The initial state of Coq declares three interpretation scopes and no lonely notations. These scopes, in opening order, are `core_scope`, `type_scope` and `nat_scope`.

As you can see, `bool_scope` where the `&&` notation lives isn't open by default.

You can either specify the scope explicitly:

```
Check (true && false) % bool.
```

or open it like so:

```
Open Scope bool_scope.
Check true && false.
```